# Get link to a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

Today, I was trying to share a comment posted on a question in the chat. But, there was no option for that. Hopefully, by a workaround I got the link to the comment. But, it would be nice if there is dedicated option for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acquire a link to a comment on a question or answer by clicking on the time/date of the comment.

For example here is a link to a comment on this question that I have acquired by right clicking on the "1 minute ago": 
[Link to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213596/get-link-to-a-comment/213597#comment687822_213596)

Comment: Never knew time/date are clickable

Comment: @Santa it is slightly surprising behaviour,  although I can't really think of annother place to put it

Comment: Yes, No one can suppose date/time can be used for this purpose